# dreamfactory : Querying records with multiple filters

Tags: android, sqlite, api, dreamfactory

I am working on an ecommerce android app. I am trying to fetch records using dreamfactory API for android, based on multiple filters.

Using an AsyncTask named as GetProductsBySubCatIdTask

```
 public class GetProductsBySubCatIdTask extends BaseAsyncRequest {

 Context context;
 public Products productsRec;
 int subCatId;
 String sort_str,fltr_str;

 public GetProductsBySubCatIdTask(Context context, int subCataId, String   sort_str, String fltr_str){
     this.context    =   context;
     this.subCatId   =   subCataId;
     this.sort_str   =   sort_str;
     this.fltr_str   =   fltr_str;
 }

 @Override
 protected void doSetup() throws ApiException, JSONException {
     callerName = "getProductsBySubCatId";

     serviceName = AppConstants.DB_SVC;
     endPoint = "product";
     verb = "GET";

     // filter to only select the contacts in this group

     if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(fltr_str)){
          fltr_str =  "&&"  + fltr_str;
      }
      else{
          fltr_str = "";
      }

      queryParams = new HashMap<>();
      queryParams.put("filter", "sub_category_id=" + subCatId + fltr_str);
      queryParams.put("order", sort_str);


      applicationApiKey = AppConstants.API_KEY;
      sessionToken = PrefUtil.getString(context, AppConstants.SESSION_TOKEN);

  }

   @Override
   protected void processResponse(String response) throws ApiException, JSONException {
     //Log.d("Tang Ho"," >>>>> " + response);
     productsRec =
             (Products) ApiInvoker.deserialize(response, "", Products.class);
   }

  @Override
  protected void onCompletion(boolean success) {
     if(success && productsRec != null && productsRec.products.size() > 0){
         Log.d("Tang Ho"," >>>>> Success");
     }
  }
}
```

I have used filters which is constructed outside the class and provided as parameter, the possible filters are

```
unit_offerprice < unit_mrp<br>
unit_offerprice = unit_mrp<br>
(unit_offerprice > 200) && (unit_offerprice > 500)<br>
unit_offerprice > 100<br>
unit_offerprice < 600<br>
```

All the above filters can be used either individually or in combination of 2 or 3 like

```
unit_offerprice < unit_mrp && unit_offerprice > 100
```

After escaping the symbols in the string like

```
unit_offerprice%3Cunit_mrp
```

Not able to get desired result, 
Searched in documentations but din't found exact thing.

what can be the possible solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your filter has multiple conditions, each condition needs to be placed inside parentheses (). Additionally, the proper syntax for joining filters with and is AND, not &&.
Supported logical operators are AND, OR, and NOT.

In your example, this:

```
unit_offerprice < unit_mrp && unit_offerprice > 100
```

should be this:

```
(unit_offerprice < unit_mrp) AND (unit_offerprice > 100)
```

See these portions of the documentation:
http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Features/Database/Records#Filtering_Records
http://wiki.dreamfactory.com/DreamFactory/Tutorials/Querying_records_with_logical_filters

DreamFactory also offers a number of official support avenues, including user forums. http://www.dreamfactory.com/support

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved by adding parenthesis for multiple filters.

But there was issue using the special characters (like <,>) and
this needed to be

encoded into %3C (for <) and %3E (for >),
the string used for the filtering is :

"(unit_offerprice>100)AND(unit_offerprice<500)"

the encoded form is :

"(unit_offerprice%3E100)AND(unit_offerprice%3C500)"